# Using RDP to access laptop in another room, I'm always logged in as "other user"

Tags: remote-desktop, steam, oculus-rift

As the title says.  I have a laptop that lives in another room of my home.  I want to remote into it sometimes from the PC in my office.  Windows 10 Pro on the laptop, 10 Home on my desktop.  Any time I do this, I momentarily see on the remote machine that I am logging in as "Other User" despite having used my own credentials.  Nobody else has ever used this machine or ever will, it is my remote gaming machine primarily for VR.

Doing general "Windows stuff" on the laptop remotely works fine.  However this completely breaks any use of SteamVR as Steam thinks I'm logged in as a user that doesn't have access to run the OVRServer_x64 runtime, and things break quite badly.  If I reboot the machine and use it manually by walking to the other side of the house and doing whatever I need to do locally on the machine, everything is fine.  This is only an issue if an RDP connection has ever been made.  Once one has, this issue is "permanent" until next reboot of the laptop.

What is causing this, and how can I stop it logging in as anything but my user, so that I can actually use it remotely and also access SteamVR from my headset?

Comment: You're sure that the "other user" thing is related to your SteamVR issue? Because I'm not. Windows always says "Other user", when a RDP session is active, regardless whether it is really another user or yourself from remote. ("user" is actually the combination of userid and source of the connection. Userid matches but source doesn't (local console vs. remote)) And it is quite plausible  that SteamVR simply refuses to operate over RDP, because the RDP video-driver (this is NOT the same video-driver as on the host computer) lacks features that SteamVR needs.

Comment: But steamVR isn't operating over RDP.  I only need RDP to be able to, say, unzip a game download or put a game file someone has sent me, into the right folder, etc.  Then I'm just back to VR without RDP connected at all.  But if an RDP session has been opened, then everything goes to crap.  I've found other people corroborate the same problem going back years to the first releases of the Rift headset.  I'm fairly certain this is related because as long as I don't ever connect over RDP, everything works perfectly.  Also Steam runs fine with RDP running, but the headset doesn't receive an image.

Comment: That just proves my point. It is a generic issue with the VR software with RDP. Not related to the user-account used for RDP. It's either Steam or Oculus or a combination of both. I never used any of that stuff (due to an eye-issue just a few seconds of "3D"is enough to give me a major migraine, I avoid it like the plague) , so I wouldn't know exactly were it goes wrong.

Comment: Yeah I see what you're saying, but to add to this... the same basic problem happened with the Oculus software itself if RDP was connected.  it wouldn't launch, mystery errors, couldn't repair or reinstall, etc.  But it turns out that if I RDP in, and manually launch OVRServer_64.exe *as this "other" user*, then it runs fine.  This wasn't the case with SteamVR, but it sure seems to point to a user account issue, does it not?